# Implementing a TypeScript generic function that converts strings to primitive types

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Is it possible in TypeScript to implement a generic function that automatically converts a string value to a primitive type specified as the generic function's type argument?

Basically I would like to do something like this:

```
const v1: boolean = getValue<boolean>("false"); // returns false
const v2: number  = getValue<number>("2345");   // returns 2345
const v3: string  = getValue<string>("2345");   // returns "2345"
const v4: number  = getValue<number>("false");  // throws an error
```

Comment: TypeScript types are erased during compilation so once that has happened there will be no way to know what the target type is anymore. Generally speaking, to do anything in TypeScript, first think about how you would do it in plain JavaScript, since ultimately that is what you will end up with.

Comment: How would such function behave when passed any other type? Like function, or object, or even any?

Comment: If you will only call it with an explicit type parameter, why not just have separate functions with different names? One of them already exists - `parseFloat` - and the one for strings is a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

```
/** Every primitive compatible with a string template */
type Primitive = number | bigint | boolean | string | null | undefined;

function getValue<T extends Primitive, U extends `${T}` = `${T}`>(value: U):
  U extends `${number}` ? number :
  U extends `${bigint}` ? bigint :
  U extends `${boolean}` ? boolean :
  U extends `${null}` ? null :
  U extends `${undefined}` ? undefined :
  string extends U ? Primitive :
  string {
    // implementation
}
```

[See in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAdgVyQCMI4oAfKIhAcwV2AqoHtmAbCAQ1yYGdhEuGkwJs2TfLgAmEAGb0IUgNwAoFTIDGbTnGizJGtMx40IwAGqc2+CAB4AKlAgAPYBGm9YiFGkwAaKABVJ1d3KU8AAwASAG97AF8IqBxouMSAPgAKdCsbAC4ggEo8lSggkLcPKFSCYlJEqAB+PEISMhKy4JdK8OrY6joGBuaB+kYO8u6wyP7WDm5hlnYuHgmu0Kqa-DFF0XE1ium+mMkZeVxFRdO5BSkoCf5BYSmq4Ob4ZFQMaAeBehpVOoIFodNANMZ+FRaAVRgxAQB6eFQeiyUi6O4aTi8CC8FSZTLFFp1MhYdJQUwWXIQTIAcgAjAAmADMABYaYVCqp8YTYYxSeSzJZrNTUgNEhyuQSYXMVskyRShTZaQIbOzOXipVBHv85QLKcLlTjgGrJYS9rqFVTaXsTRrCddzooLYKrTSHbdbWpESEwGwEBpUFBMdjcdyCrU2s79TZbBHSFl6cy2RK7TDaGMo4q7LysqLaOL1WGlvMePzLcLbEQZdwEyqILai+ayy6K3sEzaU0X3Rc7s3o3Zu4oE4OpJ6VN6UM4ncGcRrJ4oCqLq7hyHG4OLpctuKvWqRM1b51JO5lDwVEyymTSmG7pDce+zw7u4OQR-uDYfj6eoInWVfKHnBmADciTacheTfJUP0LTJJAAa1wZgAHdcAAZT+IQCm1IRCQ+Hxvgg6k4IQ5C0KeFMvSRNFmDIGdcW9MoAFooAAK3wSFELgYxhG4BDgE4IxcBUcsYzXBNZCsbF2QRJFGKgJBOFgnUsV4QgwAEzxOCrfBGFsLCaHSIEQV0IMIUYIikNQ9CaEwqzTUfYkCJg3B4Is0j-mPHll0c8ySKsjybKebznOIyyyOgs1tnEPssyclzfLCuyoFfaKrR80L3PC+zIxS1snyyNK3OwzLi1lHKYyrLdcHy4LXL84q9II3SrOquL0qKxKm3lFsRMilqQsKmh-KS29HV7Lr+1sEc+tqhKKL1GKCr8qBEIQMQoCsRDOBATxdGAfA4B4XCvkwcckWAAALBBPCuky4F0QwAiIbT1twBCQH+AA6Ob7BQqAABlPj49SSm9ZgLr3JqnjJc6uCkTgNBh3FhLsPSsgAIkZVk0c5KBvQQpw7uogJeHoDRoAxpM0eRDStSs1NacCsqUeaw1+BNXGkR+qA-R8fiEGMCZvV4SAA1kd6hCgRxzqxcplNoHsqBAZFgE8M5OG2RhMhSWIEiSbWYj0hocD0wpSg55FcH4WGoGYWQqAgHUUTRRQPsl862ICYIboa7g7l4783DZvwze9X2tWYKBwZM6QvmMKwoF2-aeFASAnByax+JxSOI6O3xoDD-29KAA), where I’ve included a bunch of test cases for your perusal.

Note, you do not need to specify `T`, and usually shouldn’t. Mostly, you should just write `getValue("1234")`, and use the fact that it returns `number`.

But if you do write `getValue<number>("true")`, you will get an error, because `"true"` is not a valid `` `${T}` ``, that is, not a valid `` `${number}` ``.

Bear in mind that this is only useful if the string values are known (or limited to a specific subset) at compile time. If you pass in a `string`, you won’t be able to tell what you’ll get out, which is why my penultimate case just repeats all the possible options, because there’s no way to know what the string actually holds (if you pass in a *known* string, that we can *tell* is not a number, boolean, null, or undefined, that’ll just get returned as `string`, which I presume is what you would do).

Beyond that, explicit `getValue<string>` annotation is going to cause headaches. It doesn’t meaningfully restrict anything, since `getValue<string>("1234")` is perfectly valid as `"1234"` is a `` `${string}` `` (that is to say, it is a `string`). And because it doesn’t meaningfully restrict anything, we can’t infer that it returns `string`—because it might return, say, `number` if the runtime value is `"1234"`. The signature above correctly captures this, but it means that `getValue<string>` is close to useless. Worse, even if you **do** have a specific string, adding `<string>` will turn off inference for `U`, and instead TS just uses the default value of `` `${T}` `` (which is the same as `` `${string}` `` which is the same as `string`). So even `getValue<string>("test")` will return `Primitive`, even though `getValue("test")` will return `string`.

One other useful feature is that this handles type unions gracefully. If you have `(val: '1324' | 'false') => getValue(val)`, it will return `number | boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, since Typescript erases types at compile time, you should instead specify the type as a parameter. I will leave the JS implementation up to you, and more specifically focus on getting the return type correctly.

Notably, you can't get an inferenced return value, specifically like `false` or `"2345"`, this is just a limitation of how we infer the values.

```js
// bigInt, Symbol, not given, but can be supported
const getValue = <T extends boolean | string | number, U extends `${T}`>(
  s: U, 
  t: T extends string ? "string"
    : T extends number ? "number"
    : T extends boolean ? "boolean"
    : never
): T => {
  return null! // Implementation left up to you
}

const v1: boolean = getValue("false", "boolean"); // returns false
const v2: number  = getValue("2345", "number");   // returns 2345
const v3: string  = getValue("2345", "string");   // returns "2345"
const v4: number  = getValue("false", "number");  // throws an error
```

View this on [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZG4eW)